# Problema with nvm_install and chef-client first run

Tags: node.js, chef-infra, cookbook, nvm

I`m using nvm chef cookbook with nvm_install resource to install nodejs and npm.

```
nvm_install 'v4.2.2' do
  from_source false
  alias_as_default true
  action :create
end
```

After install node I tried to run 'npm install' but i had this error:

> No such file or directory - npm

I`ve tried to put a "source" to load nvm.sh script but didnt work when I run chef-client at the first time.

```
append_if_no_line "Global .bashrc and source to nvm" do
  path "/etc/bash.bashrc"
  line "[[ -s #{node['nvm']['directory']}/nvm.sh ]] && . #{node['nvm']['directory']}/nvm.sh  # This loads NVM"
end
```

My question is, How can I run NPM INSTALL after install NVM/NODE with the chef-client running.

CODE:

```
nvm_install 'v4.2.2' do
  from_source false
  alias_as_default true
  action :create
end

append_if_no_line "Global .bashrc and source to nvm" do
  path "/etc/bash.bashrc"
  line "[[ -s #{node['nvm']['directory']}/nvm.sh ]] && . #{node['nvm']['directory']}/nvm.sh  # This loads NVM"
end


execute "npm install" do
  cwd "#{PATH_CODE}"
  command "npm install"
  action :run
end
```

Comment: Do you reload the bash profile before you try to run npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned on IRC, you need to handle this in each subshell you run from Chef. A better solution is probably to use poise-javascript to manage versions within Chef.

Comment: It'd be really helpful if you had mentioned here in your answer what you  had mentioned on IRC... I'm stuck in the same issue. Could you please be more specific?

Comment: As I said, the solution is probably to use one of the newer javascript runtime management cookbooks.